# Getting one error in pom.xml

Tags: maven, spring-boot

I just create a new-project.even for the new projects its gives error that commented below:

Multiple annotations found at this line:

- Plugin execution not covered by lifecycle configuration: org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:
   3.1:testCompile (execution: default-testCompile, phase: test-compile)

  - Plugin execution not covered by lifecycle configuration: org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:compile 
    (execution: default-compile, phase: compile)
- Plugin execution not covered by lifecycle configuration: org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:
   2.6:testResources (execution: default-testResources, phase: process-test-resources)
- Plugin execution not covered by lifecycle configuration: org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:
   2.6:resources (execution: default-resources, phase: process-resources)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should install or update [M2Eclipse](http://www.eclipse.org/m2e/). Go to "Help > Install New Software..." and type the following URL: `http://download.eclipse.org/technology/m2e/releases/`. Select all the elements and continue with the install. Don't forget to reboot Eclipse at the end of the process.

Once you made that, right-click your project and select "Maven > Update Project...".

Comment: as of september, 2022, it shows "could not find http://download.eclipse.org/technology/m2e/releases/"

Comment: Updated Link:- https://download.eclipse.org/technology/m2e/releases/latest/

Answer (score 3):

Just enclose your `<plugins>` tag with `<pluginManagement>` tag like the following

```
<pluginManagement>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>jaxb2-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.6</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>xjc</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>xjc</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                    <sources>
                        <source>src/main/resources/xsds</source>
                    </sources>
                    <packageName>com.concretepage.article_ws</packageName>
                    <clearOutputDir>false</clearOutputDir>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
```